# How to host webapps alongside the server.app based web tools?

Tags: server.app, webserver

Assuming this is possible, what is the recommended method of running multiple webapps alongside the web based apps (wiki, etc) that come with osx server.app ?

Answer (score 1):

Server.app provides a Websites service which can be used to publish your own web content. This service provides support for web apps (alongside normal websites) through the use of **webapp.plist**(8) and **webappctl**.

> You can define the web apps managed by webappctl by creating plist files and placing them in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapps/. For information about these plist files, enter `man webapp.plist` in Terminal.

<sup>https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.2/#/apd85e35fbb-8fc2-44ed-855f-bf4e67374de6</sup>

Comment: This looks promising. It's a bit painful though, on my server machine (running Server.app 5.2 and MacOS 10.12.1), following the documentation's suggestion I get:
`% man webapp.plist -> No manual entry for webapp.plist`

Comment: Try opening a new terminal window. Sometimes the manpath gets messed up, if the window was open before Server was installed. Does man webappctl return anything?